# Tag sequential order vs Reading order - PDF tagging using Adobe Acrobat Pro

Tags: pdf, accessibility, uiaccessibility

While tagging a PDF using Adobe Acrobat Pro, what's the correct way to fix the reading order of how the document is read by Assistive technologies? 
When I fix the order in Tags panel, the sequence in the reading order panel becomes incorrect. When I change the order in reading order panel, Tag sequential order seems to be off. If Screen reader reads according to the Tagging order, then what's the purpose of Reading order panel?

What's the procedure to make both tagging order and reading order consistent?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've always adjusted the tag order and that seems to be honored by JAWS and NVDA.  I have never adjusted things with the reading order panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tags panel should be the only location where you need to set the order. You can pretty much ignore the "*Order*" panel.

The only situation I'm aware of where this may not work as intended is if the "*Tab Order*" setting was changed from the default value of "*Use Document Structure*".

This setting can be found under `Page Thumbnails Panel` > `((Select All Pages & Right Click))` > `Page Properties`.

[image]